# Remove a node in binary search tree

Tags: binary-search-tree, removechild

I am reading a book about removing a node from a binary search tree right now and the procedure described in the book seems unnecessarily complicated to me.

My question is specifically about removing a node that has both left and right subtree. In my opinion, node-to-remove should be replaced by the rightmost node in its left subtree or by its left node if its left subtree only has one node.
[image]

In case No.1, if we remove 40, it will be replaced by 30; in case No.2, if we remove 40, it will be replaced 35.

But in the book, it says the replacement should be found from node-to-remove's right subtree which could involve some complex manipulations.

Am I missing something here? Please point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have pointed out is correct, the deleted node should be replace by **either** its in order successor which is the left most node in the right sub-tree or its in-order predecessor which is the right most node in the left sub-tree. This allows the tree to be traversed correctly. Most binary search tree data structures allow the deletion to be performed either way but in some cases special cases you might want to implement deletion such that the tree remains balanced.

More details and sample code is available on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion).

Answer (score 0):

In case no.1 if you remove node 40 it will be replace by 50.

In case no.2 if you remove node 40 it will be replace by 50.

So basically when we delete any node that has 2 child then the removal should be as below.
We go the right child of the node, and then extreme left of that child.

Below figures shown some example, how to delete a node from binary search tree. This is also taken from one book, but it is clearly explained.

[image]
 [image]
 [image]

Comment: Please see Vishal's answer and read the wiki link. Replace node-to-remove with either the rightmost child of it's left subtree or the leftmost child of its right subtree would work, it's just choosing from the right subtree would prevent an unbalanced tree from happening, which will cause inefficiency in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and the beautiful graphical explanation.

Comment: @S.H. always choosing the in-order successor will eventually cause the tree to become unbalanced. If you randomly choose between the in-order successor and predecessor then its less likely that your tree will become unbalanced. If you need a balanced binary search tree then you need to create a function to balance the tree on insertion and deletion, if you want to see an example of how this is done take a look at the [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for the supplement. My question then becomes why most text books are picking in order successor?? What makes it better than in order predecessor?

Comment: @S.H. that's mostly for historical reasons, the deletion algorithm was proposed by Hibbard in [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321108). If you are interested you can read more about some of the effects of this choice if you check for papers that cite the linked one. At least one book from Sedgewick, which I checked recommends randomizing the choice so it might be best to refer a few different books if you have doubts in the future.

Comment: This solution applies only when successor is a leaf node. There's an edge case here - what to do in the case when successor has a right child?